# bash to search file and create new file based off of input

Tags: bash, curl

In the `bash` below a file (getCSV) is downloaded by `curl` and a user inputs an id, that id is searched for in the getCSV file that as downloaded.  Currently the `curl` works and the user can input the id, but then the `bash` closes.  What I would like is that when an id is entered on the screen a display message "searching, please wait" is displayed and if a match is found then on the screen "match found in line... displays and a file is written to the directory.  If no match is found then that is displayed on the screen.  Thank you :).

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "establishing connection and downloading file, please wait"
cd 'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\wget'
curl -# -o getCSV.txt http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/data/getCSV.csv


printf "Download complete, what is the id of the NGS patient: "; read id
[ -z "$id" ] && printf "\n No ID supplied. Leaving match function." && sleep 2 && return
[ "$id" = "end" ] && printf "\n Leaving match function." && sleep 2 && return

result=`grep -n "${id}" getCSV.txt`
if [ -n "$result" ]; then
echo "match found in line $result"|sed 's/:.*//'
echo "$id"|sed 's/[^:]*://' >> match.txt
else
echo "no match found"
fi
```

**Code Edit**

So something like:

```
input=$id    
while read -r line
do
if [ -n "$id" ]; then
echo "match found in line $id"|sed 's/:.*//'
echo "$result"|sed 's/[^:]*://' >> match.txt
else
echo "no match found"
fi
done
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: bash closes without either of your error messages printing?

Comment: yes, the bash closes without printing either message on the screen, but a match.txt file is created. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to wait on user input with something like a `read varname`

Comment: so something like the code edit in the original post?  Thank you :).

Comment: Depends on what you're after; if you only want it to wait after executing the code one time you could just put a read at the bottom, and it would wait until someone hit return/enter, after having done all the above logic.

Comment: I am not sure if `read varname` will do everything in post 1, but it will certainly help. Thank you :)